How can I use one object to mask another object?
I have a boat, on a plane of water.
The plane of water goes partially up the side of the boat (the inside of the boat has no water, due to a Boolean modifier).
I want to erase the entire plane of water everywhere where you cannot see the boat through the water. Basically, I want to use the boat's sides to mask off any of the water that's not overlapping the boat visually.
Here's what I currently have:

Here's a mockup of what I want:

I'm thinking I should use the boat itself as a screen-space mask of the water. As such, I've generated a "matte" to use as a mask...

...but I can't figure out how to feed the mask to my water plane's shader. I don't want to mask off everything, just the plane of water.
What's the easiest way of masking off the water? I'm using Blender 4.1
